# Is it possible to query several fields containing a list of string values (Realm Java)

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I am trying to query several fields at the same time that contains a list of string values in Realm. 
Lets say that I have the following Object:

```
public class Article extends RealmObject implements Serializable{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Required
    private String aID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String authors;
    private RealmList<Tag> tags;
}
```

I would like to query all the articles what title, or description, or tags contain the list of strings.

I know that the predicate "**in**" can be used to match a list of values to a field as follows:

```
realm.where(Article.class)
    .in("title", listOfValues,Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .or()
    .in("description", listOfValues, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .or()
    .in("tags.tag",listOfValues, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .findAll();
```

This will only return "**matching**" values, but I am looking for "**containing**" values. There is also the "contains" predicate, but I think it can only be compared to one value.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I think you'll need to iterate and use `contains`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yeap, I was thinking to do that. Are you planning to include something similar into the backlog? I will post the solution meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question to remove the useless `.beginGroup`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A work around to solve this question is as @EpicPandaForce suggested in his comment, iterate and use contains. Here is the code for doing this:

```
 RealmResults<Article> newResults;
 RealmQuery<Article> where = r.where(Article.class).beginGroup();
 for (String keyword : keywords) {
     where = where.contains("name", keyword, Case.INSENSITIVE)
             .or()
             .contains("description", keyword, Case.INSENSITIVE)
             .or()
             .equalTo("tags.tag", keyword, Case.INSENSITIVE);
 }

 newResults = where.endGroup().findAll();
```

Comment: the `.beginGroup()` and `.endGroup()` are useless here because there a not other groups or outside criterias

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer is to directly use `.contains` (sadly it's not explained in realm-java doc).

```
realm.where(Article.class) 
    .contains("title", listOfValues, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .or()
    .contains("description", listOfValues, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .or()
    .contains("tags.tag",listOfValues, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .findAll();
```

From Realm-Java code you can find 2 methods :

```
public RealmQuery<E> contains(String fieldName, String value);
public RealmQuery<E> contains(String fieldName, String value, Case casing);
```

Comment: "From Realm-Java code you can find 2 methods" because there are only two methods, can you reference the `contains(String fieldName, List<String> listOfValues)` method? I don't think there is such method, anyway.

Comment: maybe they changed the API since my answer ? I don't use Realm anymore (because I don't work anymore on the project I used to)